# how to check if variables equal each other

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I am trying to check if two variables are equal to each other. If they are, I want to reset a variable and change another. Here is my sample code:

```
eq = int(input("\nhow many equations do you have? "))
matrix = [[] for _ in range(eq)]
solution = [[] for _ in range(eq)]
for i in range(eq*eq):
    q = 0
    x = 0
    a = int(input("input the coefficients to your variables in your equation: "))
    matrix[x].append(a)
    q += 1
    if q == eq:
        q = 0
        print("It's time to move on to the next equation!")
        x += 1
```

The problem is the if statement. Everything else works fine.

Comment: You set `q` and `x` to `0` on every iteration of that loop.

Comment: It's more common to have two loops, the inner on columns and the outer on rows — tell me if you need an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the comment from user2357112. I think you need to modify your code like below:-

```
eq = int(input("\nhow many equations do you have? "))
matrix = [[] for _ in range(eq)]
solution = [[] for _ in range(eq)]
q = 0
x = 0
for i in range(eq*eq):
      a = int(input("input the coefficients to your variables in your equation: "))
      matrix[x].append(a)
      q += 1
      if q == eq:
        q = 0
        print("It's time to move on to the next equation!")
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the `q = 0` on line 5.

`q` gets set to 0 every iteration of your loop.